# Gottesman-Knill theorem -- last measurement step

Tags: stabilizer-state, gottesman-knill

In the Gottesman-Knill theorem, the stabilizer set is updated after each Clifford gate. These steps are quite simple. At the end, the measurement is simulated. In some on-line explanations, I have seen seen that the stabilizers could be diagonalized to obtain a set of stabilizers of the form $I_1 \otimes \cdots I_{i-1} \otimes X_i / Z_i \otimes I_{i+1} \otimes \cdots I_n$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$. I do not see how to achieve this last step for a stabilizer set such as $\{ I \otimes I \otimes X \otimes X, I \otimes I \otimes Z \otimes Z, X \otimes X \otimes I \otimes I, Z \otimes Z \otimes I \otimes I \}$?

Comment: Please link to the "on-line explanations" you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you're making a $Z$ measurement on qubit $i$ (if you're doing more than one measurement, you can just go through this process one measurement at a time). Let the set of stabilizer generators be $\{g_j\}$. Then, after the measurement, you know that you get an answer $\pm 1$. This means that your system is in a $+1$ eigenstate of the stabilizer $K_i=\pm I\otimes I\otimes\ldots \otimes I\otimes Z\otimes I\otimes\ldots \otimes I$. So, you know that that stabilizer must be in your list of stabilizers. The question is how to insert it. There are three different cases:

1. there exists at least one $g_j$ such that $\{g_j,K\}=0$ (i.e.\ they anti-commute). Note that if there's more than one that anti-commutes, we can rewrite the set of generators so that exactly one anti-commutes (if you have $g_1,g_2,g_3$, replace them with $g_1,g_1g_2,g_1g_3$). In the act of the measurement the anti-commuting term $g$ will be replaced by $K$ (with the $\pm$ options occurring with 50:50 probability).
2. if all the stabilizer generators commute with $K$, then there might exist a product of generators that is equal to $K$. If so, then when you find this, it directly tells you which $\pm$ version you have, and you are guaranteed to get that measurement outcome. Nothing in the state changes. To find this out, it's a simple linear calculation: can you find an $x\in\{0,1\}^{k}$ such that
   $$
   S^Tx=e \text{ mod }2
   $$
   where $S$ is the $k\times 2n$ binary matrix describing the generators, and $e\in\{0,1\}^{2n}$ is the binary vector describing $K$.
3. if all the stabilizer generators commute with $K$, but there's no product of generators that creates $K$, then we know that the number of generators, $k<n$. At that point, you can just insert $K$ into your set of generators.

Let's take the example you gave. I'll write the stabilizers as $X_1X_2,X_3X_4,Z_1Z_2,Z_3Z_4$. I'll measure qubit 1 in the $Z$ basis. $Z_1$ anti-commutes with exactly 1 term, $X_1X_2$, so my outcome will be the stabilizers $\pm Z_1,X_3X_4,Z_1Z_2,Z_3Z_4$. Note that I can also rewrite this as $\pm Z_1,X_3X_4,\pm Z_2,Z_3Z_4$, so that if I measure the second qubit in $Z$, I see that I'll get the same answer as the first measurement (that's an example of case 2).

Comment: One detail, in Point 2, $S$ is a n x 2n binary matrix, x is a 2n x 1 binary vector, the result is a n x 1 binary vector. Not a 2n x 1 vector representing the solution. By I see the point, find the subset of generators which product gives the operator $K$. Do we have to do the measurements one after the other? Or is it possible to do three measurements at the same time? In this case, if the global phase is +1, there are four possible outcomes to verify-less efficient. My goal is to understand this last step using the Gaussian elimination and not to use the more efficient Aaronson-Gottesman sln.

Comment: I'm sure you could do the measurements all in one go, but the one-at-a-time approach manages things quite nicely. One option to do it more efficiently is to think about the observables you're measuring, $Z_i$. Can you rewrite, via linear combinations, some of them to be equal to existing stabilizers? Roughly speaking, what you're trying to do is take the matrix $S$ and, via row reduction, convert the $X$-type and $Z$-type operators into identity blocks for the qubits you're measuring. That shows you which are (anti)commuting.

Comment: To conclude this entry, see [https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28292/check-if-a-pauli-string-belongs-to-a-stabilizer-tableau]